# How to get value from loop after selecting autocomplete

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

My code is below,

```
$('#pathology_test_name').keydown(function () {
    var id_no_t = document.getElementById('id_no').value;
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pathology_con/pathology_test_name_for_adding_result/" + id_no_t,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            var tot_i = 5;
            for (i = 1; i <= tot_i; i++) {

                var test_name = 'test_name';
                test_name += i;

                var test_name = ui.item.test_name;

                $('<tr class="field" id="row' + per_test_item_id + '"><td>' + test_name + '</td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#dataTabl2');
            }

        }

    }

    });
});
```

How can i get test_name value using loop.

If i use separately ui.item.test_name1, ui.item.test_name2 .......etc without loop.

Then Value comes perfect but if i use loop like my above code then value comes undefined.

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
for(i=1;i<=tot_i; i++)
            {
                 var test_name = "ui.item.test_name".i;
                 $('<tr class="field" id="row' + per_test_item_id + '"><td>' + test_name + '</td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#dataTabl2');
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. It is showing undefined. Please give me any Solution.